# Most efficient way to have R recognize " 41520092010" as "04/15/2009 20:10"

Tags: r, datetime

I need to find the duration of a large number of events by using the start and end time variables in a dataset, but both the variables encode the time in the annoying format "mmddyyyyhhmm," with the cherry on top being that the first nine months are encoded as single digits (January is " 1" rather than "01"). At least the time uses a twenty-four clock (assuming the people filling out each event did it right).

I know there has to be a fairly simple way to do this, but I can't think of one and suspect one of you fine folks have it memorized and can write it out in a couple of seconds.

Comment: Paste a `0` on it. `as.POSIXct(paste0("0", "41520092010"), format = "%m%d%Y%H%M")`.  You can make all the relevant months have zeros with something like `ifelse(nchar(x) == 11, paste0("0", x), x)` where `x` is a vector of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector `x` with character values for conversion ...

```
x <- c("41520092010", "11520092010", "121520092010")
```

... you can check this vector for 11 characters (or whatever). If an element has 11 characters, we paste a zero on the front, then convert the whole vector to POSIXt.

```
as.POSIXct(
    ifelse(nchar(x) == 11, paste0("0", x), x), 
    format = "%m%d%Y%H%M",
    tz = "UTC"
)
# [1] "2009-04-15 20:10:00 UTC" "2009-01-15 20:10:00 UTC" 
# [3] "2009-12-15 20:10:00 UTC"
```

If you don't like `ifelse()`, you can use `replace()`.

```
replace(x, nchar(x) == 11, paste0("0", x[nchar(x) == 11]))
```

or `formatC()`

```
formatC(as.numeric(x), digits = 12, width = 12, flag = "0")
```

The most efficient of these is likely `formatC()`.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility consists in using the `stringr` library in combination with the `lubridate` library:

```
DatesAndTimes <- c("41520092010","121520092010")
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
mdy_hm(str_pad(DatesAndTimes, 12, side="left", pad="0"))
#[1] "2009-04-15 20:10:00 UTC" "2009-12-15 20:10:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using Richard's suggestion because I found it easier to find the bit that guaranteed recognizing the missing zero, but yours does seem like it would be easier on the computer.